# Can "should" be a conjunction?

Tags: word-usage

In *[The Economist](http://www.economist.com/news/united-states/21666216-shutdown-would-not-much-hurt-economyat-first-i-get-up-again)*, I encountered this sentence:

> Fortunately, no such fate awaits Americans **should** the federal government shut down on October 1st.

I cannot understand how the two complete clauses — *no such fate awaits Americans* and *should the federal government shut down on October 1st — made up this sentence.

Is *should* a conjunction meaning *while*?

Comment: Here *should* means *in the case that*, or *if*. It's used in the (fading) counterfactual / "subjunctive" sense ("subjunctive" in scare-quotes lest my linguistic betters scoff at me for suggesting English has such a thing).

Comment: No, it is not a conjunction. Conjunction "if" is omitted. "Fortunately, no such fate awaits Americans ***if*** the federal government ***should*** shut down on October 1st.". You will understand it more easily. It is a subjunctive mood.

Comment: @DanBron TMFKAS?  The Mood Formerly Known as "Subjunctive"?

Comment: @Rathony: There's no need to preserve and relocate the word ***should***. Just drop the "subjunctive" verb form: *...no such fate awaits Americans **if** the federal government **shuts** down...* (or in BrE *if the government **do** that*, since we don't insist on "the government" being singular).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sorry, I don't agree with you. This will be a 10-day-without-lunch discussion.

Comment: @Rathony Quite right; there are degrees of 'distancing'  If it shuts. if it should shut , if it were to shut.